# Change a Style based on Visual State

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, visualstatemanager

*"Blend makes it simple to setup Visual States based on say `minWindowWidth`. But it would be very nice to have state-based Styles defined for `TextBlock` elements, say with `tag="header"`, `tag="body"`, and have the Setter change the Style automatically."*

Maybe I wasn't explicit enough in my initial question, let me rephrase this.

I am resizing my application window from say Landscape to Portrait. My VisualStateManager has setters which adjust the page properties based on the new minimum width.

I have multiple TextBlocks (header,body, etc) and other controls with .Text (ToggleSwitch), that I want to automatically adjust FontSize based on the new width.

Aside from manually setting every single control by name in all the states, is there a way to have the VisualStateManager do it automatically for each 'type' of Text(body/header/etc)?  My work around at the moment is to DataBind a Style for every .Text control and have the ViewModel do all the scaling. That works, but this is really something Blend is made for, right?  So I must be missing the obvious way everyone is using.

Thanks for all the good comments so far.

```
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="PhonePortrait">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NarrowMinWidth}"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="SwitchStackPanel.(StackPanel.Orientation)" Value="Vertical"/>
                    <!-- Setter to change all Body textblocks to FontSize=8-->
                    <!-- Setter to change all Header textblocks to FontSize=10-->
                    <!-- Setter to change all ToggleSwitch.Text to FontSize=8-->
                    <!-- etc..-->
```

Comment: maybe it's just me but I don't understand what you're tying to achieve. Maybe a code sample would help...

Comment: A style does not have to target all TextBlocks... if you give the style an `x:Key` then it will only be applied to controls that explicitly say `Style={StaticResource <yourKey>}`. You can make separate styles for `Header` and `Body` and then just apply those styles to the TextBlocks that you want to look similar

Comment: WPF and UWP are two different stories. The XAML UI framework in UWP is also not the same as what in WPF.  So please clarify which framework you are using. For WPF, please use [tag:wpf] and [tag:xaml] and for UWP, using [tag:uwp] and [tag:uwp-xaml] is better. Besides, I also confused with what you are want to achieve. Does Ginger Ninja's answer meet your requirement? His answer works in WPF. For UWP app, I want to know if this `TextBlock` is used as the item of `ListBox` or `ListView`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a global style. That utilizes triggers based on the `Tag`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
   <!--Default Setters Here-->
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="body">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
            <!--Insert desired state setters here-->
       </Trigger>
       <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="header">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>
            <!--Insert desired state setters here-->
       </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You can then have a default state, and Triggered setters than only affect a Textblock when an applicable tag is attached.

If you already have other styles or want to have a selection process, you may want to add a key and then use `BasedOn` within the style.

Comment: This way, you should also be able to dynamically change the Tag, and have the style automatically change. Instead of explicitly setting a {StaticResource MyStyle} and having to reset said Style.